# d3.js chart screen size shrinks when jquery dialog exceeds bottom

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, jquery-dialog

I'm having a problem in D3.js chart. There are lots of nodes in chart and everytime we click the node a jquery dialog will appear, showing some information about the node. There are some nodes at the bottom that, when I click one of them, make the jquery dialog exceed the chartsize and the chart automatically shrinks.

```
 $('#dialog').dialog("option", "position", {
     my: "left",
     at: "right",
     of: d3.event,
     offset: "20 40"
 });
```

Is there is a solution for this? It occours in Chrome and Safari but not so in Firefox.

Comment: maybe you just have to add the 'min-width' css-property to your chart container?

Comment: Is the chart inside an SVG and, if so, is the SVG set to `display:block` and has explicit width and height?